# how to close tkinter window in a called function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a python beginner and look for some help about my code.

The 1st code will create a Tk window and call 2nd code. Then the 2nd code will create a Tk window with a button, which is expected to close both 2 Tk windows by clicking.

However, I can only close the 2nd Tk window. Pls help to check how to fix the code.

Here is the 1st code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter_try2

def function1():
    root1=tk.Tk()
    root1.title("function1")
    root1.geometry('500x100')
    tkinter_try2.function2()
    root1.mainloop()   
    
if __name__  == '__main__':
    function1()
```

the 2nd code:

```
import tkinter as tk


def function2():
    root2=tk.Tk()
    root2.title("function2")
    root2.geometry('500x100')
    bt_1 = tk.Button(root2, text="close function1 & 2",command= lambda:[root2.destroy,root1.destroy])
    bt_1.pack()
    root2.mainloop()

if __name__  == '__main__':
    function2()
```

Thank you for any advises.

Comment: You need to pass `root1` as an argument of `tkinter_try2.function2()`.

Comment: first of use only one `mainloop` at a time, second, don't create multiple `tk.Tk` instances (use `tk.Toplevel` instead), third, don't use `lambda` to call multiple other functions

Comment: Your `function1` window will not appear,(you aren't running its `mainloop`)  because your `function2` won't exit until `root2.mainloop returns`.

Comment: Note that `[root2.destroy,root1.destroy]` will not execute `destroy()` on `root2` and `root1`.  It should be `[root2.destroy(), root1.destroy()]` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 your are right. After passing the arguement and changing destroy to destroy(), both the codes work! Thank you. –

Comment: @Matiiss your advice helps my code class-level well organised, thank you.